# How to sum values of two matched tables without getting duplicates in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, duplicates, subquery

[image]

I got above result in Excel after filtering two tables by (where) `tableA.cost = TableB.total`.

I tried to apply the same in SQL, but I got duplicate values.

Here is my SQL query:

```
SELECT sum(total), sum(cost)
FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON tableA.ID = tableB.ClientID
WHERE tableA.ID = 45454
  AND TableA.code= 'A'
  AND TableA.period = 1
  AND TableB.status = 71
  AND TableA.SORT = 'SS'
  AND TableB.SORT= 'SS'
```

and the result was

```
total   cost
-235.80 -47.16
```

So the `total` column was *duplicated five times* based on the row numbers in `cost` column.

Is there any way to prevent total column being <del>not</del> duplicate ?

Comment: Use `max(cost)` instead of `sum()`.

Comment: Why should you get `duplicated five times`? Your current SQL SELECT rather would return a _single row_ where column for `sum(total)` would be summed-up as expected, but column `sum(cost)` would be __n-times the costs__ that you expected (= value of `cost` from A multiplied by _count of matching rows_ in B, e.g. n = 5), right?

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. PS This seems likely to be a common error where people want some join(s) & aggregation(s) but they erroneously try to do all the joining then all the aggregating or to aggregate over previous aggregations.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization.

Comment: @hc_dev,sum supposed to be equal in both of those columns. but  sum total was duplicated 5 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sove this specific requirement with just two subqueries:

```
select
    (
        select sum(total)
        from tableb
        where clientID = 45454 and status = 71 and sort = 'SS'
    ) sum_total,
    (
        select sum(cost)
        from tablea
        where id = 45454 and code= 'A' and period = 1 and sort = 'ss'
    ) sum_cost
```

If you need to process more (or all) `id`s at once, then you could also `join` two aggregate subqueries:

```
select a.id, b.sum_total, a.sum_cost
from (
    select clientID, sum(cost) sum_cost
    from tableb
    where status = 71 and sort = 'SS'
) b
inner join (
    select id, sum(total) sum_total
    from tablea
    where code= 'A' and period = 1 and sort = 'ss'
    group by id
) a on a.id = b.clientID
group by a.id
```

---

If you always have just one record in `tablea` per `id`, then queries get simpler:

```
select 
    (
        select sum(b.total)
        from tableb b
        where b.clientID = a.id and b.status = 71 and b.sort = 'SS'
    ) sum_total,
    cost
from tablea
where code= 'A' and period = 1 and sort = 'ss' -- and id = 45454
```